# why alexa endpoints not listen to my server with 4000 port

Tags: https, alexa-skills-kit

hello i'm new to alexa skill development.and when i'm add my server url to alexa end points which listen on 4000 port and test it.it cannot communicate with endpoints. althogh,when i make get request with browser through url it perfectly send me response.

i've tried to add this url to endpoints. https://myprojecturl:4000

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 console.log(uuid);
 res.status(200).send('Done during the request');
 });

   app.post('/', function (req, res) {
 console.log("in post")
   if (!skill) {
skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
  .addRequestHandlers(handlers[0], handlers[1], handlers[2], handlers[3], handlers[4], handlers[5], handlers[6], handlers[7], handlers[8], handlers[9], handlers[10], handlers[11], handlers[12])
  .create();
}
```

this is get and post method in my server.js file which run with express.post method call all the handlers which export by index.js file

> ps:everything runs fine with localhost and ngrok.but create problem with server url

help me to establish communication with alexa skills and my server url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port needs to be in 443. From my experience it doesn't work with other port.

Comment: Thank you,i think your answer is correct.asked my senior to give me access of 443 port then i will test and let you know.